# Kivy работа с отображением текста

Tags: python, kivy, текст

Пытаюсь отобразить текст из файла целиком, не смог найти ответа.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
kv_string = """
#:import choice random.choice
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: mylabel
        text: 'Hello ' * 10
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    Button:
        text: "Generate"
        on_release: root.ids.mylabel.text = choice(app.my_list)
"""
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        with open('asd.txt', 'r') as mytxt:
            self.my_list = mytxt.readlines()
        return Builder.load_string(kv_string)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Код не мой.
id: mylabel получает текст из файла используя рандом.
Не могу сообразить как выкатить текст(статья) целиком. за раз. все сразу.

Answer (score 0):

Что то понатыкал, поправьте пожалуйста. Но оно работает.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
z = []

class MyDemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        with open('news/Main_News.txt', 'r') as mytxt:
            ss = mytxt.readlines()
            for i in range(len(ss)):
                print(ss[i])
                z.append(ss[i])

        r = ' '.join(z)

        ll = Label(text=r)
        return ll


label = MyDemoApp()

label.run()
```